# Understanding opengl's (glut) resize

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I'm reading the sample code for the bezier curve on the online version of opengl's tutorial.

I'm curious about how is resize being handled in the example cause I figure I might use it on my own version of this program , I placed my questions on its comments:

```
void reshape(int w, int h)

{
   glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h); // what's GLsizei? Why is it called inside glViewPort?
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // is it necessary to reset the projection matrix?
   glLoadIdentity();
   if (w <= h)  // is this calculation universal, could I use it on another program? 
      glOrtho(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0*(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)w, 
               5.0*(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)w, -5.0, 5.0);

   else
      glOrtho(-5.0*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h, 
               5.0*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h, -5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // why do I set to GL_MODELVIEW at the end?
   glLoadIdentity(); // why does it get a reset?
}
```

Full code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

GLfloat ctrlpoints[4][3] = {
    { -4.0, -4.0, 0.0}, { -2.0, 4.0, 0.0}, 
    {2.0, -4.0, 0.0}, {4.0, 4.0, 0.0}};


void init(void)
{
   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
   glMap1f(GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3, 0.0, 1.0, 3, 4, &ctrlpoints[0][0]);
   glEnable(GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3);
}

void display(void)

{
   int i;

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
      for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++) 
         glEvalCoord1f((GLfloat) i/30.0);
   glEnd();
   /* The following code displays the control points as dots. */

   glPointSize(5.0);
   glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   glBegin(GL_POINTS);
      for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
         glVertex3fv(&ctrlpoints[i][0]);
   glEnd();
   glFlush();

}

void reshape(int w, int h)

{
   glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h); // what's GLsizei? Why is it called inside glViewPort?
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // is it necessary to reset the projection matrix?
   glLoadIdentity();
   if (w <= h)  // is this calculation universal, could I use it on another program? 
      glOrtho(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0*(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)w, 
               5.0*(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)w, -5.0, 5.0);

   else
      glOrtho(-5.0*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h, 
               5.0*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h, -5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // why do I set to GL_MODELVIEW at the end?
   glLoadIdentity(); // why does it get a reset?
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)

{
   switch (key) {
      case 27:
         exit(0);
         break;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

   glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);
   glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
   init ();
   glutDisplayFunc(display);
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape); // el reshape funciona correctamente 
   glutKeyboardFunc (keyboard);

   glutMainLoop();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`GLsizei` is a *type*, not a function. Therefore, it's not being called; its being *casted*; it's converting an `int` into a `GLsizei`. It's basically an `int`, but it makes it clear that you're using it for a size (I think). (I'm a Python programmer, so this is a guess)

```
glMatrixMode(...);
```

This does **not** reset the matrix, unless it is followed by a `glLoadIdentity()` call. Instead, it sets the current target of OpenGL's matrix operations to the matrix specified. This way, OpenGL knows what matrix you're trying to affect.

I've seen that calcuation before in the OpenGL superbible (or at least something like it); why don't you talk yourself through it and see what it's deciding and why? (Hint (I think): it's trying to keep the viewport square to avoid stretching)

At the end, it sets it back to GL_MODELVIEW since that matrix handles transformations, like translation and rotation, which are used to position vertices onscreen. It should be reset every frame so that your code can assume that the coordinate plane is currently at (0,0); that simplifies calculations about where to translate to.

Also note that `reshape` is not called by OpenGL, but by GLUT. OpenGL is platform-independent and does not handle windowing; this is why you need GLUT.

If you're new to OpenGL, you should work through it from the beginning - later tutorials will assume this sort of knowledge.

Comment: +1 Although you are a python programmer, you got everything correct :)

Comment: The question doesn't say that glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION) resets the matrix :/

Comment: I'll change the question's title, I know (and knew) this is passed to a glut callback.

Comment: question: why is traslation and rotation relevant on a 2d program? If the coordinate plane is reset at every draw you mean that each current point is considered (0,0)?

Comment: No, not at all. Instead, at each draw call, the coordinate system is centered at (0,0), and then your code can translate and rotate. Translation is OpenGL's equivalent of "draw something at (x,y)" because you can write the code *assuming* everything is centered at (0,0), but then translate and place the drawn object at say, (20,20).